# Submit button causing layout issues

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have 2 buttons , one being a image submit button and the other just a standard link button.  The layout issue is that the image submit button pushes the other button beneath it. If i take out the form tags the 2 buttons remain side by side which is the way i wish for it to be.

any suggestion on how to make my buttons side by side while keeping the form tags (which i obviously need) ?

thanks

```
<span class="col3data">

<?php "here goes my standard link button"; ?>

<FORM method="post" target="_blank" action = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/OnlineTool">

<INPUT type="hidden" name="InquiryNumber" value="W<?php echo $history['orders_id'];?>">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="TypeOfInquiryNumber" value="R">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="SenderShipperNumber" value="xxxx">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="IATA" value="CA">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="Lang" value="eng">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="DestinationCountry" value="US">

<?php "here goes my image submit button"; ?>

</FORM>


</span>
```

my span style

```
.form_container .col3data
{
 float: left; 
 width: 37%; 
 border:1px solid #00CC33;

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the applicable markup and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe even this will do the job:

```
<input type="image" style="float: left;" ... >
```

Comment: it seems like floating left both buttons made it align properly...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you placed the regular link outside of the `<form>` tag? The reason why your link isn't next to each other is because `<form>` is a block-level element.

```
<FORM method="post" target="_blank" action = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/OnlineTool">

<INPUT type="hidden" name="InquiryNumber" value="W<?php echo $history['orders_id'];?>">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="TypeOfInquiryNumber" value="R">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="SenderShipperNumber" value="xxxx">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="IATA" value="CA">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="Lang" value="eng">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="DestinationCountry" value="US">

<?php "here goes my image submit button"; ?>
<?php "here goes my standard link button"; ?>

</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="float: left;"><input ....>&nbsp;<a href....</div>
```